# Moving lone pairs horizontally or vertically

Tags: chemfig, chemmacros

I'm trying to draw a Lewis structure with a lone pair, but when I typeset, the lone pair is not centered. How do I freely move it slightly up or move it horizontally? Please let me know.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}


\begin{document}

\chemfig{M
    ( -[:90]  A)
    ( -[:270] C)
    ( -[:0] \lewis{0:,})
    ( <[:210] D)
    (>:[:160] E)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not related to `chemmacros` (which isn't used in your example at all apart from being loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be interesting to use the `\charge` macro as suggested in the documentation (page 4): https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf. But if you use `\lewis`, it's better to use it refering an element of your `\chemfig` and not `\lewis{0:,<empty space>}` to avoid what you seen. You can put an `X` referred as an arbitrary element. Even so, I hope this code works as you want!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}    

\begin{document}

\chemfig{M
    ( -[:90]  A)
    ( -[:270] C)
    ( -[:0]\Lewis{0:,\phantom{i}\hspace{-2mm}})
    ( <[:210] D)
    (>:[:160] E)}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]